# Primefaces DataTable - deleting with dialog deletes wrong entry

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I have a table in a form. One of the columns in the table displays a row of buttons to edit and delete the table entries. When I delete an entry callign the controller from a button's `action` attribute, it works as expected.

But once I have added a dialog to let the user confirm the deletion, a wrong entry is deleted. It is always the last entry in the current table. I have no idea what the reason could be - I am using the same `DataTable` `var` for the button and for the dialog.

I am working with JSF 2 (Mojarra 2.1.6) and Primefaces 3.5 deploying on JBoss 7.1.1 on a Suse 12.2 machine.

The form:

```
<h:form id="downloads">
    <ui:include src="components/table.xhtml"/>
</h:form>
```

The table:

```
<ui:composition>

  <p:dataTable value="#{controller.currentLevelResources}"
            var="download" id="downloadTable" scrollHeight="120" rows="10">

    <p:column sortBy="#{download.name}">
        <f:facet name="header">Name</f:facet>
        <h:outputText id="downloadName" value="#{download.name}" title="#{download.description}" />
    </p:column>

            ...

    <p:column>
        <ui:include src="menuBar.xhtml"></ui:include>
    </p:column>
```

The menu bar:

```
<ui:composition>

        <p:commandButton id="edit"
            action="#{downloadEditController.editResource(download)}"
            icon="ui-icon-gear" title="Edit" oncomplete="updateStyles()"
            update=":downloads" />

        <p:commandButton id="delete" onclick="deletedDlg.show();"
            icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Delete" oncomplete="updateStyles()" />

        <p:dialog header="Delete confirmation" widgetVar="deletedDlg"
            resizable="false">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="padding:5px;">
                <h:outputText
                    value="The Resource #{download} will be deleted. Proceed?" />
            </h:panelGroup>
            <p:commandButton id="deleteBtn" value="Delete"
                oncomplete="deletedDlg.hide(); updateStyles(); "
                action="#{downloadEditController.deleteResource(download)}"
                process="@this" update=":downloads">
            </p:commandButton>
            <p:commandButton value="Cancel" type="button"
                onclick="deletedDlg.hide();" />
        </p:dialog>
```

If I replace the dialog with this, everything works:

```
<p:commandButton id="delete" icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Delete" 
action="#{downloadEditController.deleteResource(download)}" 
oncomplete="updateStyles()" update=":downloads" />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Creating a `<p:dialog>` for every row is not a good idea.

For starters you had better create a single `<p:dialog>` outside your `<p:dataTable>`.

Next thing that I would do is to set the *id or the row var* in your bean upon delete button click and in case of confirmation in dialog use that *id or the row var* from bean to delete.

This is how your delete button could look like, set the `download` var in `prepareDataForDeletion` action and show the dialog...

```
<p:commandButton id="deleteConfirmation" icon="ui-icon-trash" title="Delete" 
    action="#{downloadEditController.prepareDataForDeletion(download)}" 
    onsucess="deletedDlg.show();"/>
```

---

Regarding your current anomaly: it's because all your dialogs have the same `widgetVar` and each next one is overriding the previously declared one all the way until the last one. You could dynamically give them a different widget names like so `widgetVar="deleteDlg_#{someIndex}"`, but this makes no sense if you can have just only one reusable dialog whose content is updated before opening.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for looking into it. Do you have an idea WHY my approach is not working (I know it's the hard part of a question) - I am using the same variable after all? And WRT external dialog, how would I simultaneously set the var on my bean AND activate the dialog?

Comment: Thanks to @BalusC for the explanation of the *anomaly* :)

Comment: @BalusC - aah, now I get it. Thank you once more.